# hyperref link does not exist from cite

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, warnings

(I'm not sure the post title is good enough)

I'm using `biblatex` with `biber` and printing the bibliography by part with `refsection=part`.

The MWE below produces a warning from `hyperref`.

```
name{cite.0@foo} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

I believe it is because there is no bibliography before the first part so the citation link points to nothing.

I'd like to solve that since it is *the only warning* in my document!!

**MWE**

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{foo.bib}
@book{foo,
author = {author},
title = {title},
date = {2019},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, refsection=part, citestyle=alphabetic, backref=true, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{foo.bib}

\defbibheading{bibliography}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \chapter*{\bibname\ of \thepart}%
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
By \cite{foo}
\part{title}
Again by \cite{foo}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the warning is a symptom of the underlying problem that your first part has no corresponding bibliography.
That might not seem bad at first, but check out
`\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[backend=biber, refsection=part, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
By \cite{knuth:ct:b}
\part{title}
Again by \cite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}
\printbibliography
\end{document}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler example is the following. And yes you get the warning as the link has no target. One solution is to provide a target somewhere with `\hypertarget` (or by adding a `\printbibliography` in this refsection. Another solution would be a cite command that doesn't create a link.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
By  \cite{doody}

%\hypertarget{cite.0@doody}{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I searched a lot for this `biblatex-examples.bib`. I should record it somewhere.

Comment: *...cite command that doesn't create a link*. Does the `biblatex` package provide such command?

Comment: I didn't see one, but imho it could be useful in certain places. Make a feature request or ask @moewe.

Comment: Thanks so much. `hypertarget` worked very well.