# How to silence this warning when using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, warnings

If I use the package `hyperref` and cite a paper without printing the bibliography, I get the following warning

```
pdfTeX warning(dest): name{cite.0@<paper_name>} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

Here's an example:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@Article{doc,
Title = {A title},
Author = {Some guy}}
\end{filecontents}
%
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\begin{document}
Here is some more text using the old key \cite{doc}.
\end{document}
```

Where the warning is:

```
pdfTeX warning(dest): name{cite.0@doc} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

How can I silence this warning?

Comment: Why don't you have/want a bibliography?

Comment: I know, what I'm trying to do is to get rid of the warning without printing the bibliography. I'm dividing a project into separate chapters and don't want to print the bibliography for every chapter, just for the main document.

Comment: Somewhat related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/483222/35864

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the option hyperref=false. Then biblatex will not try to create links between citations and the non-existing bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@Article{doc,
Title = {A title},
Author = {Some guy}}
\end{filecontents}
%

\usepackage[backend=biber,hyperref=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\begin{document}
Here is some more text using the old key \cite{doc}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to turn off the links only on the single chapter documents (where the bibliography is not printed), while leaving them on in the main file, where the bibliography is present?

Comment: I have no idea how you are organizing/importing the main document and the chapters. Better ask a new question.

Comment: You're right, I just [did](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/488276/172923).