# Different behaviours when using subfiles package

Tags: subfiles

I use the `subfiles` package to divide the main document I'm working on into chapters, so that I don't have to compile the whole document everytime.

This means that I don't print the bibliography in any of the separate chapter files, I only print in the main file. When compiling the separate chapters, this results in a warning from `hyperref`, complaining about the lack of bibliography, as already discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/488270/172923).

The solution posted there is to use the package option `hyperref=false` when loading `biblatex`. This solves the problem in the chapter files, but now I don't have links in the main file.

So my question is: is there a way to differentiate the main file from the others, so that I can use some code like:

```
\ifmaindocument{\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}}
\ifsubdocument{\usepackage[backend=biber, hyperref=false]{biblatex}}
```

in the preamble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing which is different between the main file and the subfile is the name. Assuming your main file is called `main.tex`:

```
\usepackage{xstring}

\IfEq{\jobname}{\detokenize{main}}{%
    % stuff for main file
}{%
  % stuff for subfile
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your newest question gave me another idea that does not require additional packages:

```
\makeatletter
\ifdefined\preamble@file
    % stuff for the subfile
\else
    % stuff for the main file
\fi
\makeatother
```

Comment: Damn, you stalking me? Ahaha just joking. This is actually a very nice solution to both those problems, AND it doesn't require any additional packages. I'd accept both the answers if I could, thanks a lot.

Comment: @noibe I was about to answer the other question, but was 3 seconds too slow, so I thought I could to put the `\preamble@file` to good use here :)